# How to make a cycled sequence of jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins. I have a stack of 5 different jobs. I want them to execute endlessly, meaning the first one will start after successfull finish of 5th. Is there a way to do this? Is Jenkins pipeline plugin the right tool to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have 5 non-pipeline jobs, the easiest way is to
set a downstream job on each job as it makes a loop. 
In the configuration page of each job, *Add post-build action* > choose *Build other projects* > Enter a name of a downstream job.

Comment: thank you very much! Although it was an obvious option, but I was a bit afraid of the word 'project'

Answer (score 0):

in pipeline there is a build step (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/), but I haven't tried if this can take trigger itself (most probably).